# How SCNGeometry materials correspond to it's elements?

Tags: 3d

In sceneKit, geometry can set An array of SCNMaterial objects that determine the geometry’s appearance when rendered.
According to apple's doc:

> If a geometry has the same number of materials as it has geometry elements, the material index corresponds to the element index

How SCNGeometry materials correspond to it's elements?In what order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

box has six surface. the order is front -> right -> back -> left -> top -> bottom。
and the SCNMaterial object index is (index / SCNMaterial count )